# Stop when meet special word - Regex

Tags: regex

I looking for help with a specific regex : `(THE_WORD_I_WANT_TO_FIND)[^.?!\w]+([^.?!\s]+[^.?!\w]+){0,NUMBER_OF_WORDS}(MY_WORD_AT_END)`

To explain, i'm looking for a specific word before another word. I have some conditions, I want to delimit to the sentence in which the WORD_AT_END is and to a specific number of word before it.

This regex does the job but I want to add a sentence delimiter : `(\s\-\s)` (in addition to . ? !).

Example :

`Blablabla. A full Reference - Help is available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial.`

with the regex : `(Help)[^.?!\w]+([^.?!\s]+[^.?!\w]+){0,}(watch)` matchs and `(Reference)[^.?!\w]+([^.?!\s]+[^.?!\w]+){0,}(watch)` must not match...

Could you please help me?

Thank you !

**SOLUTION (Thanks to @MostafaHussein) :**

`(Help)((?!\s-\s)\s(([\w|\w-|\pL|\pL-])+(?!\s-\s)\s+){0,})?(watch)`

> Here, `-` is a sentence delimiter if it is surrounded by two spaces.

Comment: To keep it ordered, the sequence should be `(THE_WORD_I_WANT_TO_FIND)(?:[^.?!\w]+[^.?!\s]+){0,NUMBER_OF_WORDS}[^.?!\w]+(MY_WORD_AT_END)` For example, if whitespace is used as a word delimiter it would be `(THE_WORD_I_WANT_TO_FIND)(?:\s+\S+){0,NUMBER_OF_WORDS}\s+(MY_WORD_AT_END)`

Comment: Beware though that a comma for instance, will satisfy `[^.?!\s]` and `[^.?!\w]` so `,,,,,,,,,` will match and is probably not what you want.

Comment: Language is difficult for regex. And there is no way to make out a word using regex. However, a _very_ good approximation is `\s*([^\pL\pN]*[\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-])|[?.!])*)` that can be wrapped in `{0,number of words}` An ascii equivalent would be `\s*([\W_]*[^\W_](?:\w|[[:punct:]_-](?=[\w[:punct:]-])|[?.!])*)` I could blow it up for you with an explanation if interested. This `[?.‌​!]` for example is special word ending punctuation, it can be added to and used as a word boundary, or as an exclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Regex:

```
(Help)\s(?!-)(?s).+?(watch)
```

would match only:

```
Help is available in the Library, or watch
```

And not:

```
Reference - Help is available in the Library, or watch
```

As there is `-` will be found after the first word specified followed by a space e.g. `Reference -`

Update:

this regex will match any sentence as long as it does not contain `-` (it has to be surrounded by white-spaces)

```
Help((?!\s-\s)\s(([\w|\w-|\pL|\pL-])+\s+){0,7})?watch
```

[Demo URL](https://regex101.com/r/SX3Ne3/7)

Note: there has to be exactly 7 words before `watch` without counting `Help` and nothing matches if there is a `-` surrounded by spaces, also unicode letter character is taken in consideration so if there is something like `ê` will be matched correctly.

Comment: Just a heads up, `\s|\S` will match everything.

Comment: Yes until it found watch using `?(watch)` as I think he needs to match any thing starting from a specific word until a specific word but not before the dash delimiter. am i correct ?

Comment: Well, yes. My point is that `(\w|\s|\S)+?` is identical to `[\S\s]+?` or `(?s).+?`

Comment: You are right! but how could this be a problem ? this part `\s(\w)` is keeping `Reference -` from being matched

Comment: And is this part `(\w)` separate from this part `(\w|\s|\S)` ?

Comment: yes the whole regex would be `(Help)\s(\w)[\S\s]+?(watch)` or `(Help)\s(\w)(?s).+?(watch)`

Comment: This `\s(\w)[\S\s]+?` requires space + word + any = 3 characters minimum, this `\s(\w|\s|\S)+?` requires space + any = 2 characters minimum.

Comment: I have updated my answer. now requires space + word = 1 character minimum.

Comment: @sln thanks for the assist! i have learned new things here :D

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand what you mean but one case is missing (and I forgot to write it...). I'm French and we have some word which are like this : "peut-être"... Here, "-" is not a delimiter. That's why I wanted to have a space on each side of "-"

Comment: @BenjaminDelacour no problem the regex still work here is a demo https://regex101.com/r/SX3Ne3/2. it wont match only if the first word is followed by a space and `-`

Comment: this part `\s(?!-)` is to ensure that there is a space first and then `-` if found any `-` after the space then the regex wont find a match

Comment: Ok thank you !
But I've got a problem : https://regex101.com/r/SX3Ne3/3
As you see, I wrote a "-" between "peut-être" and "available" but "Help" is still matching (it must not because of the "-")

Comment: And how can I limit the number of words before "watch" instead of the number of chars?

Comment: I have updated the regex in answer which will wont work if there is a `-` surrounded by spaces. I will update the regex again as soon as i add the word limits

Comment: @BenjaminDelacour hey, could you check the final update ? Is this what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @sln can you suggest anything else that could enhance the performance of this regex while achieving the same thing ? Or there is nothing more to do ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein, I think something was missing to work : `Help((?!\s-\s)\s(([\w|\w-|\pL|\pL-])+(?!\s-\s)\s+){0,})?watch`, now it works. I found the problem testing a word far before `watch` with an hyphen in the middle. It was matching and now it doesn't. Thank you !

Comment: Could you provide an example ? I have repeated that word you told me about it and still works https://regex101.com/r/SX3Ne3/10